# Prove : $(n-1)\cdot\Gamma ( n-1)=(n-1)!$

Tags: gamma-function

To prove :

$(n-1)\cdot\Gamma ( n-1)=(n-1)!$ ; for every $n>1$

Also , is $\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$ a derived conclusion or part of the definition of gamma functions ?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gamma_Difference_Equation

Comment: There are multiple definitions of the $\Gamma$ function, for instance through the Bohr-Mollerup theorem, through the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^s e^{-x}\,dx $ or through Euler's product. Which one is the the definition you are using?